# Spring Security CSRF disable is not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, basic-authentication

I want to protect `/actuator/shutdown` endpoint with Basic auth. I have an implementation of `UserDetailsService` and my security class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public static class ActuatorWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  UserProvider userProvider;

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(new UserDetailsServiceCustom(userProvider)).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12));
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
       .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    http.authorizeRequests()
       .antMatchers("/actuator/shutdown").authenticated().and().httpBasic();
  }
}
```

I enabled shutdown endpoint like this in properties:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: shutdown
  endpoint:
    shutdown:
      enabled: true
```

When I perform `POST /actuator/shutdown` I receive 403 FORBIDDEN and with debugger I see that `UserDetailsServiceCustom` method is not triggered at all, but if I try `GET /actuator/shutdown` I receive 405 and method in `UserDetailsServiceCustom` is triggered properly, so it means that I can access this endpoint but something stands in a way of POST. I googled a lot and found out that it's because of CSRF but as you can see I've disabled it already. I also tried to add `web.ignoring().antMatchers("/actuator/shutdown")` but this way anyone can access this endpoint.

So my question is how to enable Basic Authentication that uses my database users for this endpoint?

**UPDATE**
Okay so the problem was not with the HttpSecurity config or CSRF but with how I incorrectly implemented [multiple HttpSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#multiple-httpsecurity)

Comment: How do you perform that POST? Using Postman?

Comment: yes, and tried with/without Basic authentication

Comment: This line `http.csrf().disable().requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();` worked for me

Comment: If you have solved your issue yourself, then please write down the answer yourself for future generations. If some comments were helpful, please upvote them.

Answer (score 1):

`http.csrf().disable()` is not working in Spring Boot 3.x.x. You should try the following line.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringFilterChainConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
        http.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/users").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/users/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                ).build();
    }
}
```